# Does order matter in multinomial distribution?

Tags: combinatorics

I am confused if order matters in multinomial distribution..
As far as I understand order does matter and if we want to eliminate matter of an order we need to multiply  $\frac {n!}{r_1! \cdot r_2! \cdots r_k!}$ by $\frac{1}{k!}$

having

$$\frac {n!}{r_1! \cdot r_2! \cdots r_k!} \cdot \frac{1}{k!}$$

for choosing elements from n into k groups when order of those groups does not matter. Right? Probably there is a rule for that.. I do not know. I just derived this reasoning from solving some problems and I want to check if my reasoning is right or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry, my previous, an accepted answer, was totally wrong.)

Order of events is not counted in a multinomial distribution, that is: you have $n$ disjoint possible events (named $E_k$, for $k\in[n]$) of $X_j$ i.i.d. random variables, each one with a different probability to occur such that all the probabilities add up to $1$.

Then if we define $X:=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_m$ then $X$ distributes with a multinomial distribution.

The events of $X$ are of the kind $E:=c_1E_1+c_2E_2+\ldots+c_nE_n$ such that $\sum_k c_k=m$. We dont care the order of the $E_k$ in $E$, the binomial distribution just count all possible ordering such that $E$ happen.

Comment: See [this image](http://twanvl.nl/image/knight/multinomial-law1.png)